# How to access granted media_projection thought root?

Tags: root, sql-grant, android-mediaprojection

how can I use the root command to grant permission to "media projection" or to another: "screen capture/screenshot"? maybe it's some kind of "activity" you need to run?

I tried to grant permissions, the root commands didn't help. Maybe I just presented them the wrong way

Comment: adb shell settings put secure enabled_screen_cast *package_name* NOT WORK